# JsonSerializable: How to toJson/fromJson correspond to subclass type?

Tags: flutter, dart

Let say I have data structure like this

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class CartItem {
  final Product product;
  ...
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Product {
  final String id;
  ...
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Food extends Product {
  final String foodName;
  ...
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Furniture extends Product {
  final String furnitureName;
  ...
}
```

What I want is when I use `CartItem.toJson()` it export to Json map correspond to what type of `Product` is.

For example

```
var x = CartItem(
          product: Food(
            id: '1100112',
            foodName: 'Hamburger',
          ),
        )
print(x.toJson());
```

this should result in

```
{
  'product': {
    'id': '1100112',
    'foodName': 'Hamburger',
  }
}
```

also when use `fromJson`, product will has type `Food`

```
x.fromJson(x.toJson()) as Food //This should not error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the package `json_serialization`. For each class you would want to define some of the following methods:

For example:

```
factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$CartItemFromJson(json);
```

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$CartItemToJson(this);
```

Then you would run the generating command line:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

This will auto-generate a `.g.dart` file corresponding to your
model file.

Reference: https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable

Otherwise, if you wish to define the methods manually:

```
class CartItem {
  final Product product;
  CartItem({required this.product});
  /// fromJson
  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CartItem(
      product: Product.fromJson(json["product"])
  );
  /// toJson
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "product": product.toJson()
  };
}

class Product {
  final String id;
  Product({required this.id});
  /// fromJson
  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
      id: json["id"]
  );

  /// toJson
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id
  };
}

class Food extends Product {
  final String foodName;

  Food({required String id, required this.foodName}) : super(id: id);

  /// fromJson
  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Food(
      id: json["id"],
      foodName: json["foodName"]
  );

  /// toJson
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "foodName": foodName
  };
}

class Furniture extends Product {
  final String furnitureName;

  Furniture({required String id, required this.furnitureName}) : super(id: id);

  /// fromJson
  factory Furniture.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Furniture(
      id: json["id"],
      furnitureName: json["furnitureName"]
  );

  /// toJson
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "furnitureName": furnitureName
  };
}
```

After defining, you can do:

```
var x = CartItem(
 product: Food(
  id: '1100112',
  foodName: 'Hamburger',
 ),
)
print(x.toJson());
```